# Distributed File Synchronization

Tags: filesystem, sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my own Dropbox / Ubuntu One server at home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home)

First of all I should define what I mean with "distributed" - I mean to have the same file copy on each associated computer. If I change the file on one machine, all other copies have to be actualized automatically. Furthermore each client saves a local revision.

*(I know that's practically the same as Dropbox, but Dropbox doesn't allow me to use my own root server and I have terabytes of space there I intend to use)*

Now to the problem:

- [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) for example can recursively synchronize folder contents. I doesn't store revisions. 
  Git could act as a content tracker (it's not necessarily just source control), but it is definitely not supposed to handle large files or binaries at all. An approach like [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) sounds interesting, it doesn't synchronize if files are changed. It just schedules rsyncs and takes revisions.
- Is there anything in FUSE like an rsync filesystem? - There are approaches for backups, but backups and file-sync are two very different use-cases: a backup can be scheduled at a specific time, like at night or so. A synchronization occurs if a file is changed, which is handled as an event
- if this really doesn't exist: do you consider it being possible to have an rsyncfs like [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) or [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), acting as a FUSE mount point?