# How to create file/folder sync functionality (similar to Dropbox)?

Tags: dropbox, sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my own Dropbox / Ubuntu One server at home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home)

I think with time it will become possible to use a Dropbox locally on my Linux/Unix/Windows server. But for now, I would like to synchronize Ubuntu/Windows Xp/7 machines with Linux server (Linux file server). Does anybody have positive solution for Dropbox-like sync software in Ubuntu?