# How to install Ubuntu One server software or alternative for personal use?

Tags: server, ubuntu-one, sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my own “dropbox, ubuntu one” server at home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home)

I have a Debian based box in my house that runs as a webserver, and a 4GB bootable usb-stick with Ubuntu. I need to store stuff on a server and Ubuntu One seems an ok way to go but I find that 2GB is not sufficient.

I can most likely solve that when I install this server software. Where can I find it - there is no ubuntu-one-server package or similar in the Software Centre.

How can I install the Ubuntu One server software or an alternative?