# How to set-up my own cloud server?

Tags: software-recommendation, cloud, file-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my own Dropbox / Ubuntu One server at home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home)

I am a student, 17 years of age and wanting to access all of my files at greatest ease. i would like to have a system like this:

Computer A, B and C are the computers on which I work and to which the files should be available.
Server A is located in my room and I can install Ubuntu on it.

What is the goal? I want to edit files on computer A (e.g.) and computer A should update the file on my server, afterwards the server should update the files on computer B and C. (The same goes for editing files on computer B, afterwards the server has to update the files on A and C.)

I don't want to have a restriction of disk space, as I already have my own server, so things like Dropbox won't work for me.

How am I able to set-up a network like this? It is about music, movies, pictures, documents...

Comment: You misunderstand "cloud", I believe.

Comment: And they deleted one of my answer for being not helpfull.... ^ -.-'

Answer (score 4):

KDE's OwnCloud software should work nicely for you.

Here's an article on how to set it up: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/owncloud-2-your-personal-cloud-server.html

Comment: Nice web ui, easy to use, client on most platforms. Unfortunately android's client isn't free.

Answer (score 2):

WMRKameleon, here is my recommendation.

To set a chain of network is not in my knowledge, but for the set-up procedure of the cloud-type software, maybe I can help.

---

First of all, you can freely use the OwnCloud. You need to install the LAMP server, because this app require the PHP, Apache and MySQL to work on.

http://owncloud.org/

The best thing is, you can integrate your nautilus file manager with the OwnCloud directly without accessing the web-based version. Meaning, just like you do the FTP through a webserver directly from the nautilus without depending on the FileZilla FTP client or FireFTP. Just like using the Ubuntu-One with nautilus integration on the Ubuntu (hope you already used the Ubuntu-One, and you know what am I talking about the direct nautilus integration and so on...). Oh, the integration that I'm talking about called as WebDAV....

If you can set up chained-network (cloud) of computer using the LAMP (or any other ways), just use this. If don't, put this in the single computer can be done easily.

---

Sparkleshare is another opensource option. It doesn't need LAMP, but does require `git`. Like git, it's not so great for large binary files that change often, but it's awesome for maintaining change history on large text files.

http://sparkleshare.org/

Hope this helped...

Answer (score 1):

I've never personally used it, but it sounds like [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) is what you're after. You can [set up your own server](http://sparkleshare.org/set-up-a-host/), or use a free one. SparkleShare is a cloud storage solution based on git.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple solution would be to download the Opera web browser and use Opera Unite. It can make setting up file sharing servers very easy. I don't know about the change a file on B and it will up update on A (the server) and therefore C, but you can upload files to the server remotely so you could do it like that manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 more pretty tricky answers to the question and require you go do some research.

`First :`

Only 1 server is hosting the files, and run as the NFS host, then the rest of the servers mount the NFS to the NFS host.

`Second :`

If all servers must also have the files, then setup Heartbeat+NFS to clusterize all 3 servers.

Those answers are from my friend on the Facebook. Actually, we don't need to setup a cloud-networked computer to do a fileserver if the resources on the single PC are good enough to support its standalone-operational-cycle.

If we are trying to run a cloud-based company, then we will need multiple of PCs connected to each other to balance the resource usage (called as loadbalancer). 1 PC will control the resouce of the MySQL usage, the other will control the HTTP request (you can use the LiteSpeed or Apache or Nginx) and the other one will control something else. That's the definition of the cloud itself.

If we are using to store our files (assume that we are going to store a lot of files), increase the diskspace up to 1TB or 5TB or use the CPU with mutilple hard disk bay, or just buy the NAS storage.