# Personal Cloud Server

Tags: cloud, home-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make my own Dropbox / Ubuntu One server at home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home)

Ok, so what I'm wanting to do is turn my old computer into an Ubuntu based cloud server that i can access from outside my home wifi network. For example, I'd like to be able to access all the information on my server from my smartphone while I'm at school or at work. Could someone please explain to me how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to access files, or interact with the server? Commandline or Desktop?

Comment: I want to access files on the server, for example i want to be able to pull files off the server onto my other devices, and vice versa, or simply stream files off the server.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not so much a cloud server, as a file server. There are many resources about setting up a file server with Ubuntu. Your precise setup will depend on several things.

Some questions on AskUbuntu:

1. [How to make my own Dropbox / Ubuntu One server at home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home?lq=1)
2. [How do I use Ubuntu Server as file server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126850/how-to-use-ubuntu-12-4-server-as-file-server)
3. [How to set-up my own cloud server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78876/how-to-set-up-my-own-cloud-server)

Some articles on the web:

1. http://www.wesg.ca/2009/05/build-a-ubuntu-fileserver-the-planning/
2. http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=3967
3. http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-12.10-samba-standalone-server-with-tdbsam-backend
4. http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-a-home-media-and-file-server-with-ubuntu